# Why is my SVG failing to load in Vector Asset Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, svg, android-vectordrawable, androidsvg

The SVG below is failing to open in Android Studio's Vector Asset Studio in resulting in the error:

"Empty preview image!
EXCEPTION in parsing TareSymbol.svg:
For input string: "8.7337904mm"Exception while parsing XML file:
Premature end of file."

Why is the following SVG file not compatible with Vector Asset Studio?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg20235"
   viewBox="0 0 61.500162 30.946501"
   height="8.7337904mm"
   width="17.356712mm">
  <defs
     id="defs20237" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata20240">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     transform="translate(-109.24987,-351.17467)"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       d="m 145.03542,367.34167 10.897,-4.49325 -0.009,3.30587 13.69124,0.0372 1.13537,0 0,2.1285 -1.13537,0 -13.69662,-0.0373 -0.009,3.33988 -10.87325,-4.281 z m -13.38814,-13.15875 0,-3.00825 16.97389,0 0,3.00825 -6.8995,0 0,27.93825 -3.15214,0 0,-27.93825 -6.92225,0 z m 3.31725,13.15875 -10.897,4.49325 0.009,-3.3055 -13.69129,-0.0373 -1.13537,0 0,-2.1285 1.13537,0 13.69662,0.0372 0.009,-3.33988 10.87325,4.28063 z"
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none"
       id="path20212" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Well In my case it was imported successfully. Probably a newer version now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Importing the .svg files produced in Inkscape into Adobe Illustrator and exporting them fixed this issue 100%.

Comment: Well... Inkscape is free, and often used as the "poor man" 's Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: Not a solution if you are using Sketch.

Comment: How can I export an image using sketch?

Answer (score 42):

Android Studio's Vector Asset Studio is currently not support all the features of SVG. You can convert SVG to VectorDrawable using this [tool](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion but unfortunately this doesn't work either.

Comment: Check out this [Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpXtYoE-NCk) for your further references.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I can confirm that this tool worked for me on a particular svg file where one of the paths was left out by Android Studio.

Comment: This tool is deprecated now. It suggests to use Android studio's vector asset tool but it still gives an error.

Answer (score 16):

My SVG was being created (from an online website) with `,` in the `viewbox` tag.

i.e:

`viewBox="0, 0, 350,450"`

changing this to:

`viewBox="0 0 350 450"`

allowed Android Studio to import it

Answer (score 15):

You need to change the width and height of the svg from `mm` to use `px` instead. This is a current workaround pending when the issue is fixed.

There is already a filed bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189654)

Answer (score 10):

After spending some hours, I figured out the problem, and even using external ***svg2vectordrawable*** scripts couldn't help.

The size of the shapes and/or the document's page size cannot contain floating numbers in its width/height such as 14.134 or 3.5

Meaning the width and height of the shape and the page must be **integers**!

Comment: Yep this is it. Thanks, any idea if they added this to the most recent version 3.1.2 and it wasn't there before ?

Answer (score 9):

As **@Kingsley Adio** said, you must use `px` units for your SVG document.
In Inkscape, I managed to do it by creating a custom page size and setting the output unit to `px`:

[image: Inkscape Document Properties]

Answer (score 1):

Compilation of things that worked for me when trying to import SVGs with the `Vector Asset` tool (they are not mutually exclusive):

- Change values from `mm` to `px` (typically found in the `width` / `height` attributes)
- Round values float values to integer (typically found in the `width` / `height` or `viewBox` or `style` attributes). Like `224.5`. You won't have to do this in the polygons, but only on the SVG node.

Comment: For SVGs from https://www.flaticon.com seems to be working perfectly so far. Already imported more than 10 SVGs following this guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the language in settings helped me! I had Dutch as language on my computer (where comma's are used instead of floating points) and changing it to English and restarting worked for me.

Comment: Hey, thanks for contributing Unfortunately your question could be classified as low effort, albeit it could be technically correct. Please try to include details into your answer, such as step-by-step way to change the floating point symbol, so it  can be used as a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Changing Text to Object fixed this issue for me.
If you are using Inkscape: first click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (Path Combine) then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Dynamic Offset).

Answer (score 0):

There are **various option** that might cause such an error (some of them listed here).

On causing could be the use of `rgba(r,g,b,a)` in your .svg file. Just check and convert if found.

Hint: You can edit .svg fils in any file editor.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I was using **Illustrator 2015**. Problem turned out to be I had multiple artboards in my illustrator project and I had to choose one particular artboard when saving as svg file (why it does so? no idea).
**Solved by having only one artboard containing the design** I want to save as svg.

1. Make sure your illustrator design has only one artboard containing
   the design you want to use as vector asset in android studio.
2. In Illustrator File->Save as->select svg from dropdown. Keep all
   other options as default.
3. Go to android studio, right click on drawables and click vector
   asset and import your newly created svg file. It would be saved as
   an xml file in drawables.