# Internal error parsing svg file in android studio

Tags: android-studio, svg

Start from this month, I was not able to import any svg file though Vector Asset in my laptop, I always get the msg 'Internal error parsing abc.svg'

I tried to import same svg file using android studio in other laptop, it works, but my laptop cannot import anymore.

I was using android studio in my laptop around 2 years and has been go through many updates, but this month suddenly cannot import anymore, I had performed factory reset in my laptop, and re-install android studio again. I tried create new project as well, but it still cannot work, anyone can help me?

[image]

Comment: **follow this link and see Figure 3.** https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my SVG failing to load in Vector Asset Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906986/why-is-my-svg-failing-to-load-in-vector-asset-studio)

Comment: Is the other laptop running an older version of Android Studio?  If so, it sounds like a bug. You should report it.

Comment: Not, its updated version.

Comment: Look at that
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906986/why-is-my-svg-failing-to-load-in-vector-asset-studio/37337205

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**UPDATE December 23, 2018**

Base on [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73334521) seems this bug fixed in Android Studio 3.2 Canary 5 and above so update your android studio is another way to fix! now i use version 3.2.1 and work fine.

**OLD ANSWER**

Finally i found solution. I don't know what going on but i have same problem and fixed when i download same svg again and open it with notepad++ and export it with different name as svg! and it's work!

**EDIT**

If you use [**flat icon**](https://www.flaticon.com/) for download svg, before download just click on edit and then download! this svg work fine in android studio.

I have android studio 3.1.1

This just a bug in android studio

**EDIT 2**

There is another bug in decimal numbers in svg viewBox that can be fixed by change decimal to integer (thanks to crgarrido)

Sample :

Change decimal numbers to integers numbers in svg file header

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 375 135.4">
```

Change **135.4** to **135**

Comment: If crgarridos answer did help you solve the issue, please mark his post as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: personally use flat icon and work fine when just edit it

Comment: @KokSoon change it back after you import it

Comment: Updating from Android Studio 3.1 to 3.4 worked for me

Comment: This answer helped me: I had `viewBox="0,0 12,12"` - replace commas with spaces and it works. Android Studio bug #12971369924

Answer (score 61):

In my case, I had a decimal value indicating the height, rounded it to an integer solved the issue

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 375 135.4">
```

Changing the **135.4** to a **136** did the job

**Update**

After that, In the *IDE Fatal errors section* I constated the following exception:

[image: NumberFormatException]

The vector assert parser fails when you have a decimal dimension, I reported the issue. I hope it will be fixed soon.

Comment: This was my issue. Thank you!

Comment: This is indeed should be the best answer. Worked for me too.

Comment: had to remove decimals from viewBox & width but worked fine

Comment: it work for me, but the icon doesnt look nice anymore, anyway, thx

Comment: @KokSoon I experimented kind of the same, but it was a render issue in a device, I solved using AppCompatImageView. Actually, when you modify the viewbox of the svg, you are just modifying the "rectangle" where is being drawn, the shape itself remains exactly the same.

Comment: Isn't that solution changing the original icon? I was able to get around this issue by using https://androidassetstudio.net/, basically, all my icons were generated fine in the android studio except one, that I solved by using this website.

Comment: This did it for me!

Answer (score 15):

I had this error too, and I think I got an answer.

When you "Add a Vector Asset" in your project, Android Studio creates a .xml file in res/drawable folder.

So I found this website : http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/

You just have to drop your .svg file in the box and wait a few seconds.

Then, just right click on drawable folder in Android Studio, New -> Drawable resource file, set the icon name, etc...
And you finally replace the content by the xml code the website gave you.

Save the file, and your icon is ready to go !

Comment: Unfortunately this became a paid tool

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem adding width and height to the svg tag.

Example

From

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 43.42 56.15">
```

To

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 43.42 56.15" width="24" height="24">
```

I guess Android Studio can't add vectors from svg files without mentioning the dimensions.

Comment: @KokSoon I know. You need to customize your vector after you import the svg. But at least you won't have errors on importing the svg into your project.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you have to convert all float number to integer.
for example open .svg file in text editor

```
 width="292.362px" height="292.362px" viewBox="0 0 292.362 292.362" style="enable-background:new 0 0 292.362 292.362;"
```

change to

```
width="292px" height="292px" viewBox="0 0 292 292" style="enable-background:new 0 0 292 292;"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your SVG file.
You must set the page measure to be in pixels.

With Inkscape, in Windows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to open the Document Properties. Set the size units to pixels (px).

Hope it helps. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: But why i use my colleague laptop can be import, but my laptop cannot be import? we both tried import the same svg file, and my laptop can view the svg file in chrome, are you sure is the svg file problem ?

Comment: Of course I'm not sure. The only way I could be sure is if I was handling the situation myself. I'm only going by what you tell me. But yes, it's most likely an svg problem. Have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: I tried your idea, i did open Properties but i didnt see any size units, i cant find anywhere to set pixels (px).

Comment: Android Studio 3.1.1, i think it should be the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by removing the comma separated values in the `viewBox`, i.e. I had

`viewBox="0, 0, 350,450"`

and changing it to

`viewBox="0 0 350 450"`

allowed it to be imported

Answer (score 0):

I used Gimp and Export Path to produce a simple SVG. It had the width and height as decimal inches. Changing these to the pixel width/height fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

**w: 85.3 h:120.4px**  ==> **w:85px H:120px** its ok and work

Answer (score -1):

Open your SVG file in Notepad. 
Round all the decimal values in viewBox ="no decimal values allowed here".

Answer (score -2):

I was able to solve this internal error by parsing abc.svg error problem, please change `width="512px"` and `height="512px"` and it should work.

[image]

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.