# Internal error parsing while adding SVG image in Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, svg

I am trying to add SVG image using add new vector asset but while adding I am getting an internal parsing error in latest Android Studio version 3.1.3. Please help me out. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtjh8.png)

Comment: This is not enough information. Add more detailed info and to make your question interesting otherwise people will find your question boring and will close it.

Comment: Make sure that the dimensions of the svg file contain no decimal values. E.g. `width=25.5` should be `width=25`. This is one of the most common errors

Comment: The SVG converter does not have very good error handling, and crashes for some innocuouse and valid SVGs. For example it crashed if the viewBox has commas in it.  Please post the SVG in your question so we can offer better advice.

Comment: Or maybe try another converter, such as http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/

Comment: Yea Paul, it's working fine with this converter, but in the previous version conversion was never required I was able to access it directly using vector drawable.

Comment: check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49974482/6401241

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/ go to this side and upload svg files and download android drawable files xml format.